# Python eyed3 check for embedded image

Tags: python, eyed3

I need a script to check a whole directory for mp3 files without an embedded image.
This function should return such a list.

```
def checkAlbumCover( file_list ):
    ret = list() #list with mp3 files without album cover
    for f in file_list:
        mp3 = eyed3.load( f )
        if len( mp3.tag.images ) == 0:
            ret.append( f )
    return ret
```

With another function I go through every directory and sub directory and get all filepaths. Then I check if they are mp3 files and if not I delete them. So finally I have a list with  173 mp3 files (in my case). The filepaths are correct, however, the function above gives me errors.

**output :**

```
173 mp3 files found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_album.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "get_album.py", line 18, in main
    list_without_image = checkAlbumCover( all_files )
  File "get_album.py", line 10, in checkAlbumArt
    if len( mp3.tag.images ) == 0: # 0 images embedded
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'images'
```

What did I do wrong?

**Edit:**
I printed out `f` before checking for an image and it seems that my function already checked 20~ files before crashing.

I 'fixed' it:

```
if mp3.tag is None: # 0 images embedded
    ret.append( f )
```

However, I don't really understand why `tag` is `None`...

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're running into is that some of the mp3's you are working with do not have ID3 tags. When that is the case, eyeD3 is returning `None` for their tag value, and that is crashing your program.